# C++ Pass struct & function pointer across DLL boundary

Tags: c++, dll, struct

In Kernel.dll, there defines the struct & function pointer:

```
struct Data // blahblah
void (*Callback)(const Data & data);
```

In Tool.dll, there's a util function:

```
void GetData(Callback callback)
{
    // create a thread with "ThreadProc()" method, and pass the callback in
}

void ThreadProc()
{
    Data data;
    // fill the struct
    if (callback) callback(data); // this "callback" is the callback func ptr passed to "GetData()" func above.
}
```

In main.exe, there's the real logic:

```
void OnData(const Data & data)
{
    // do something
}

int main()
{
    GetData(&OnData);
}
```

Everything runs well, but then "a heap is corrupted".

The hell is, even I remove all codes in the "OnData" handler, the corruption is still there. But if I don't pass any callback function (nullptr), the corruption is gone. It seems that the function passing to the DLL is triggering the problem.

What's the magic of "DLL boundary"? These days I have heard quite a lot about such things. What technique leads to this magic "boundary"? And what kind of things need special attention?